# Load Chrome extension before loading all elements of the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to load my Chrome extension before all the elements of the page load (instead of after). Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by extension you mean content script then the most you can do is set `"run_at": "document_start"` property in manifest which means

> "[content script] files are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run."

[(read more)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html).

You won't be able to communicate with your background page before the page starts loading though as there is no synchronous message passing.