# Load two pages in parallel and combine the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension inserts HTML from page B into page A by using a content script to make an AJAX request:

**manifest.json**

[...]

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "js": [
      "jquery-1.11.0.min.js", 
      "myscript.js"
    ],       
    "matches": [
      "*://www.pageA.com/*",
    ]
  }
]
```

**myscript.js**

```
$.get('www.pageB.com/' + getPage(document.URL), function(data) {
    $(data).find('#page_B_element').insertBefore($('#page_A_element'));
});
```

However, this only starts downloading page B once page A has partially rendered, so there is a noticeable delay before `$('#page_B_element')` is inserted.  This is true even if the Javascript is injected immediately after page A is received, using [`"run_at": "document_start"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467257/load-chrome-extension-before-loading-all-elements-of-the-page) in `manifest.json`.

- Is it possible to request page B immediately after page A is *requested*, and download both pages in parallel?  This is not possible client-side with ordinary web pages, but could an extension achieve this with something like the [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API?
- Failing that, is there at least a non-[hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7638185/1397061) way to show page A and the inserted element from page B at the same time?

Edit:

Note that page B depends on the subdomain requested on pageA.com, so it's not just a matter of caching page B.  This was not clear in the original post.

Comment: use a placeholder, cache pageb in head, or hide everything with a loading screen until ready.

Comment: @dandavis Good idea about a placeholder/loading screen if all else fails.  I can't cache page B - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to have the pageB_element retrieval in a background script? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages

In that case, there would be an initial performance hit, but thereafter you would have a cached copy of pageB_element (inner html) which you can then immediately insert in page A.

Comment: I can't cache page B (see my edited post), but good idea about using event pages - it might be possible to use the webRequest API to trigger an event page.